# How to properly configure multiple DMLCs to listen to a single sqs queue?

Tags: java-8, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

We have an order managament system in which after every order state update we make an api call to our client to keep them updated. We do this by first sending a message to a sqs queue and inside a consumer we hit our clients api. The processing on consumer side usually takes about 300-350ms but The approximate age of oldest message in sqs dashboard is showing spikes that reach upto 50-60 secs.

Seeing this I thought that maybe one consumer is not enough for our load and I created multiple DMLC beans and multiple copies of our consumer class. I attached these consumer classes as listeners in these DMLCs. But I have not seen any improvement in approximate age of oldest message.
I am guessing that maybe only one of the DMLC is processing these messages and others are just sitting idle.

I added multiple DMLCs because there are other places in pur codebase where the same thing is used, But now I am not sure if this is the correct way to solve the problem.

My Consumer class looks like this:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HOAEventsOMSConsumer extends ConsumerCommon implements MessageListener {

  private static final int MAX_RETRY_LIMIT = 3;
  private final OMSEventsWrapper omsEventsWrapper;
  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
      TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
      String jmsMessageId = textMessage.getJMSMessageID();

      ConsumerLogging.logStart(jmsMessageId);

      String text = textMessage.getText();
      log.info(
          "Inside HOA Events consumer Request jmsMessageId:- " + jmsMessageId + " Text:- "
              + text);
      processAndAcknowledge(message, text, textMessage);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
      log.error("JMS Exception while processing surge message", e);
    }
  }

  private void processAndAcknowledge(Message message, String text, TextMessage textMessage) throws JMSException {
    try {
      TrimmedHOAEvent hoaEvent = JsonHelper.convertFromJsonPro(text, TrimmedHOAEvent.class);
      if (hoaEvent == null) {
        throw new OMSValidationException("Empty message in hoa events queue");
      }
      EventType event = EventType.fromString(textMessage.getStringProperty("eventType"));
      omsEventsWrapper.handleOmsEvent(event,hoaEvent);
      acknowledgeMessage(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      int retryCount = message.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount");
      log.info("Retrying... retryCount: {}, HOAEventsOMSConsumer: {}", retryCount, text);

      if (retryCount > MAX_RETRY_LIMIT) {
        log.info("about to acknowledge the message since it has exceeded maximum retry limit");
        acknowledgeMessage(message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my DMLC configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class HOAEventsOMSJMSConfig extends JMSConfigCommon{

  private Boolean isSQSQueueEnabled;

  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer hoaEventsOMSConsumer;
  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer2 hoaEventsOMSConsumer2;
  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer3 hoaEventsOMSConsumer3;
  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer4 hoaEventsOMSConsumer4;

  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer5 hoaEventsOMSConsumer5;

  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer6 hoaEventsOMSConsumer6;

  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer7 hoaEventsOMSConsumer7;

  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer8 hoaEventsOMSConsumer8;

  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer9 hoaEventsOMSConsumer9;

  @Autowired
  private HOAEventsOMSConsumer10 hoaEventsOMSConsumer10;


  public HOAEventsOMSJMSConfig(IPropertyService propertyService, Environment env) {
    queueName = env.getProperty("aws.sqs.queue.oms.hoa.events.queue");
    endpoint = env.getProperty("aws.sqs.queue.endpoint") + queueName;
    JMSConfigCommon.accessId = env.getProperty("aws.sqs.access.id");
    JMSConfigCommon.accessKey = env.getProperty("aws.sqs.access.key");
    try {
      ServerNameCache serverNameCache = CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(ServerNameCache.class);
      if (serverNameCache == null) {
        serverNameCache = new ServerNameCache();
        serverNameCache.set(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
        CacheManager.getInstance().setCache(serverNameCache);
      }
      this.isSQSQueueEnabled = propertyService.isConsumerEnabled(serverNameCache.get(), false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      this.isSQSQueueEnabled = false;
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public JmsTemplate omsHOAEventsJMSTemplate(){
    SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory;
    if (endpoint.toLowerCase().contains("localhost")) {
      sqsConnectionFactory =
          SQSConnectionFactory.builder().withEndpoint(getEndpoint("sqs")).build();
    } else {
      sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
          .withAWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
          .withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(10)
          .withEndpoint(endpoint)
          .build();
    }
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(queueName);
    jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(false);
    jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(false);
    jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return jmsTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerHOAEventsListenerContainer() {
    SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory;
    if (endpoint.toLowerCase().contains("localhost")) {
      sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
          .withEndpoint(getEndpoint("sqs"))
          .build();
    } else {
      sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
          .withAWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
          .withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(10)
          .withEndpoint(endpoint)
          .build();
    }
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    dmlc.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
    dmlc.setDestinationName(queueName);
    dmlc.setAutoStartup(isSQSQueueEnabled);
    dmlc.setMessageListener(hoaEventsOMSConsumer);
    dmlc.setSessionTransacted(false);
    dmlc.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    
    return dmlc;
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerHOAEventsListenerContainerNo2() {
    SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory;
    if (endpoint.toLowerCase().contains("localhost")) {
      sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
          .withEndpoint(getEndpoint("sqs"))
          .build();
    } else {
      sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
          .withAWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
          .withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(10)
          .withEndpoint(endpoint)
          .build();
    }
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    dmlc.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
    dmlc.setDestinationName(queueName);
    dmlc.setAutoStartup(isSQSQueueEnabled);
    dmlc.setMessageListener(hoaEventsOMSConsumer2);
    dmlc.setSessionTransacted(false);
    dmlc.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return dmlc;
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerHOAEventsListenerContainerNo3() {
    SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory;
    if (endpoint.toLowerCase().contains("localhost")) {
      sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
          .withEndpoint(getEndpoint("sqs"))
          .build();
    } else {
      sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
          .withAWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
          .withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(10)
          .withEndpoint(endpoint)
          .build();
    }
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    dmlc.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
    dmlc.setDestinationName(queueName);
    dmlc.setAutoStartup(isSQSQueueEnabled);
    dmlc.setMessageListener(hoaEventsOMSConsumer3);
    dmlc.setSessionTransacted(false);
    dmlc.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(SQSSession.UNORDERED_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return dmlc;
  }
}
```

If this question is already answered somehwere else, then please point me towards that.

Comment: What is the visibility timeout configuration for the queue? It's possible you are seeing messages that failed processing (or otherwise go unacknowledged) and are in the queue, but invisible to consumers until the visibility timeout expires. If your expected processing speed is less than one second, you'll want your visibility timeout to be closer to that time frame -- the default is 30 seconds which is obviously way too big if your processing time is sub-second.

Comment: Visibility timeout is 30 secs the default value only. And I do not see any error in logs for these consumers, so I don't these are msgs which failed to process.

Comment: Check your [queue metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) for in-flight (visible/not visible) messages. If your _visible_ message metric is high, then that may confirm your consumers have a problem. But if it's just in-flight/not visible messages, then the visibility timeout is likely your problem. If your consumer picks up the message, but doesn't ack/delete for any reason, that only has to happen twice for the oldest age to reach 60 seconds.